# AngularJS controller in spring app doesn't work on amazon AWS

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, spring-mvc, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a spring app with the following controller, it works on localhost (it works with the following error but it works never the less -

```
angular.min.js:13620 TypeError: Cannot read property 'cartItems' of undefined
    at ChildScope.$scope.calGrandTotal (controller.js:34)
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.min.js:14540), <anonymous>:4:230)
    at expressionInputWatch (angular.min.js:15679)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.min.js:17221)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.min.js:17501)
    at bootstrapApply (angular.min.js:1696)
    at Object.invoke (angular.min.js:4551)
    at doBootstrap (angular.min.js:1694)
    at bootstrap (angular.min.js:1714)
```

)

When I lunch the app on Amazon AWS, on the elstastic beanstalk (on tom cat), it doesn't work at all, it shows the following errors:

```
angular.min.js:13620 TypeError: Cannot read property 'cartItems' of undefined
    at ChildScope.$scope.calGrandTotal (controller.js:34)
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.min.js:14540), <anonymous>:4:230)
    at expressionInputWatch (angular.min.js:15679)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.min.js:17221)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.min.js:17501)
    at bootstrapApply (angular.min.js:1696)
    at Object.invoke (angular.min.js:4551)
    at doBootstrap (angular.min.js:1694)
    at bootstrap (angular.min.js:1714)
    at angularInit (angular.min.js:1604)

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
angular.min.js:13620 TypeError: Cannot read property 'cartItems' of undefined
    at ChildScope.$scope.calGrandTotal (controller.js:34)
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.min.js:14540), <anonymous>:4:230)
    at expressionInputWatch (angular.min.js:15679)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.min.js:17221)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.min.js:17501)
    at done (angular.min.js:11600)
    at completeRequest (angular.min.js:11813)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.min.js:11741)
```

Controller:

```
var cartApp = angular.module ("cartApp", []);

cartApp.controller("cartCtrl", function ($scope, $http){

    $scope.refreshCart = function () {
        $http.get('/DesignAnna/rest/cart/'+$scope.cartId).success(function (data) {
           $scope.cart=data;
        });
    };

    $scope.clearCart = function () {
        $http.delete('DesignAnna/rest/cart/'+$scope.cartId).success($scope.refreshCart());
    };

    $scope.initCartId = function (cartId) {
        $scope.cartId = cartId;
        $scope.refreshCart(cartId);
    };

    $scope.addToCart = function (productId) {
        $http.put('/DesignAnna/rest/cart/add/'+productId).success(function () {
            alert("Product successfully added to the cart!")
        });
    };

    $scope.removeFromCart = function (productId) {
        $http.put('/DesignAnna/rest/cart/remove/'+productId).success(function (data) {
            $scope.refreshCart();
        });
    };

    $scope.calGrandTotal = function () {
        var grandTotal=0;
        var lenght = $scope.cart.cartItems.length;

        for (var i=0; i<lenght; i++) {
            grandTotal+=$scope.cart.cartItems[i].totalPrice;
        }

        return grandTotal;
    };
});
```

view:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@include file="/WEB-INF/view/template/header.jsp" %>

<div class="container-wrapper">
    <div class="container">


                <div class="container">
                    <h1>Cart</h1>

                    <p>All the selected products in your shopping cart</p>
                </div>
            </div>


        <section class="container" data-ng-app="cartApp">
            <div data-ng-controller = "cartCtrl" data-ng-init="initCartId('${cartId}')">
            <div>
                <a class="btn btn-danger pull-left" data-ng-click="clearCart()"><span
                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span>Clear Cart</a>
                        <a href="<spring:url value="/order/${cartId}"/>"
                   class="btn btn-success pull-right"><span class="glyphicon-shopping-cart glyphicon"></span> Check out
                </a>
            </div>

            <table class="table table-hover">
                <tr>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th>Unit Price</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
                <tr data-ng-repeat = "item in cart.cartItems">
                    <td>{{item.product.productName}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.product.productPrice}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.quantity}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.totalPrice}}</td>
                    <td><a href="#" class="label label-danger" data-ng-click="removeFromCart(item.product.productId)">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>remove</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Grand Total</th>
                    <th>{{calGrandTotal()}}</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <a href="<spring:url value="/product/productList" />" class="btn btn-default">Continue Shopping</a>
            </div>
        </section>

    </div>

    <script>


    </script>


<div class="container-wrapper">
    <div class="container">


<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/controller.js" /> "></script>
<%@include file="/WEB-INF/view/template/footer.jsp" %>
```

On localhost, it has the error I stated above however everything works fine, on the Elastic beanstalk it doenst work at all though.

Cart resources:

```
package com.myWebPage.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.security.core.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

import com.myWebPage.model.Cart;
import com.myWebPage.model.CartItem;
import com.myWebPage.model.Customer;
import com.myWebPage.model.Product;
import com.myWebPage.service.CartItemService;
import com.myWebPage.service.CartService;
import com.myWebPage.service.CustomerService;
import com.myWebPage.service.ProductService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/rest/cart")
public class CartResources {

    @Autowired
    private CartItemService cartItemService;

    @Autowired
    private CartService cartService;

    @Autowired
    private CustomerService customerService;

    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;

    @RequestMapping("/{cartId}")
    public @ResponseBody Cart getCartById(@PathVariable(value = "cartId") int cartId) {
        return cartService.getCartById(cartId);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add/{productId}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void addItem(@PathVariable(value = "productId") int productId, @AuthenticationPrincipal User activeUser) {

        Customer customer = customerService.getCustomerByUsername(activeUser.getUsername());
        Cart cart = customer.getCart();
        Product product = productService.getProductById(productId);
        List<CartItem> cartItems = cart.getCartItems();

        for (int i = 0; i < cartItems.size(); i++) {
            if (product.getProductId() == cartItems.get(i).getProduct().getProductId()) {
                CartItem cartItem = cartItems.get(i);
                cartItem.setQuantity(cartItem.getQuantity() + 1);
                cartItem.setTotalPrice(product.getProductPrice() * cartItem.getQuantity());
                cartItemService.addCartItem(cartItem);

                return;

            }
        }
        CartItem cartItem = new CartItem();
        cartItem.setProduct(product);
        cartItem.setQuantity(1);
        cartItem.setTotalPrice(product.getProductPrice() * cartItem.getQuantity());
        cartItem.setCart(cart);
        cartItemService.addCartItem(cartItem);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/remove/{productId}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void removeItem(@PathVariable(value = "productId")int productId) {
        CartItem cartItem = cartItemService.getCartItemByProductId(productId);
        cartItemService.removeCartItem(cartItem);
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "{CartId}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void clearCart(@PathVariable(value = "carttId")int cartId) {
        Cart cart = cartService.getCartById(cartId);
        cartItemService.removeAllCartItems(cart);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(IllegalArgumentException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, reason="Illegal request, please verify your payload")
    public void handleClientErrors(Exception e) {}

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, reason="Internal server error")
    public void handleServerError(Exception e) {}

}
```

Cart Controller:

```
package com.myWebPage.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.myWebPage.model.Customer;
import com.myWebPage.service.CustomerService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/customer/cart")
public class CartController {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerService customerService;

    @RequestMapping
    public String getCart(@AuthenticationPrincipal User activeUser) {
        Customer customer = customerService.getCustomerByUsername(activeUser.getUsername());
        int cartId = customer.getCart().getCartId();

        return "redirect:/customer/cart/"+cartId;
    }

    @RequestMapping("{cartId}")
    public String getCartRedirect(@PathVariable (value="cartId")int cartId, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("cartId",cartId);

        return "cart";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var lenght = $scope.cart.cartItems.length; // typo var length
```

Check if $scope.cart is defined or initialise it

Comment: Thanks for the response, I initialized the var $scope.cart, and changed and added if ($scope.cart.cartItems !== undefined) before the loop, it made the error go away, But it still does not work on the amazon aws... it works fine on local host though.

Comment: Can you give more details about the part that does not work?

Comment: On the elastic beanstalk - Even if the user has products in the cart, it shows cart as empty and grandTotal as 0. There are no errors however, and in the console I can see that both the angular.min.js and the controller are loaded. 

Everything works perfectly on localhost, and doesn't work on the elastic beanstalk, do you have any idea what i might be missing?

Comment: The addToCart function does not update the model locally. How does that work on localhost?

Comment: I added the cart resources and controller code that hold the cart functionality, hope that helps

Comment: So the only way to get the cart contents is through $scope.refreshCart() so you need to call it when addToCart resolves. Still this looks like code that cannot work on localhost or any other. Are you sure it's the same code on the remote server?

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it - I changed the controller to jQuery, it still did not work, all I needed to do is to remove the project name from the endpoint.. feel kinda silly but there it is.